# detect users' operation on browsers

Tags: javascript

How to use JavaScript to detect user operations on browsers such as click backward/forward/refresh button, keyboard inputs in navigation bar or search bar of FireFox, as well as any hotkeys for these operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Anything that happens outside the page content area is completely off-limits to scripting. (Thank God... it would be a security and usability disaster.)

About the only information you can get is that if an `unload` event happens without a link being clicked/form submitted, the user did some kind of navigation outside the page (such as window close, bookmark open, address entered, back/forward/etc). And if you really want to be obnoxious you can detect/prevent browser-specific navigation keystrokes like F5-for-refresh when the focus is in the window.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for mouse/keyboard events on the page's DOM or the window, you can detect. The easiest way for me is using JQuery's event: http://docs.jquery.com/Events

Anything else e.g clicks on the browser toolbars/search boxes/3rd party components will be highly unlikely (I'm hesistant to say 100%).

Navigation of pages/url can be detected as well but not necessarily identified as back/forward or refresh.

Comment: Any idea of not using JQuery? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, JQuery is made up of pure javascript. You can implement your own. A good reference for event handler: http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/js_eventhandler.html Good luck!